# Graceful reload of python tornado server

Tags: python, tornado, upgrade

I have an HTTP server created by the Tornado framework. I need to update/reload this server without any connection lost and shutdown.

I have no idea how to do it.
Could you get me any clue?

Comment: what does mean reload/update?

Answer (score 1):

## Easy way, do it with nginx.

1. Start a latest tornado server.
2. Redirect all new connections to the new tornado server.(Change nginx configure file and reload with `nginx -s reload`)
3. Tell the old tornado server shutdown itself if all connections are closed.

## Hard way

If you want to change your server on the fly, maybe you could find a way by reading nginx's source code, figure out how `nginx -s reload` works, but I think you need to do lots of work.